# bash: ./*.exe: No such file or directory with executables named *.exe

Tags: debian, executable

Looks like I cannot run any normal linux binaries if their name ends with `.exe`, any idea why?

```
$ cp /bin/pwd pwd
$ ./pwd
/home/premek
```

This is ok. But...

```
$ cp /bin/pwd pwd.exe
$ ./pwd.exe 
bash: ./pwd.exe: No such file or directory

$ ls -la pwd.exe 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 premek premek 39616 May  3 20:27 pwd.exe

$ file pwd.exe 
pwd.exe: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=2447335f77d6d8c4245636475439df52a09d8f05, stripped

$ ls -la /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 May  1  2019 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
$ ls -la /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 165632 May  1  2019 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
$ file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=f25dfd7b95be4ba386fd71080accae8c0732b711, stripped
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I spent one day on this and of course 1 second after posting this question I remembered something like this existed to register .exe files for wine:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/wine 
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/wine
flags: 
extension .exe
```

and `/usr/bin/wine` did not exist.

I got rid of it using:

```
$ sudo update-binfmts --remove wine /usr/bin/wine
update-binfmts: warning: no executable /usr/bin/wine found, but continuing anyway as you request
```

and it works now

Comment: Ugh; why doesn't that work by recognizing MZ ... PE headers?

Answer (score 17):

Most UN*Xes, including Linux, recognize native executable files (ELF files, in the case of most modern UN*Xes, including Linux) by a "magic number" that appears at or near the beginning of the file.

Windows binaries are in the [Portable Executable format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format), which also has magic numbers - the file begins with a stub MS-DOS executable, [which begins with a magic number containing the letters "MZ"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable), and also has a separate "PE" magic number, at a variable offset.

According to [the kernel.org documentation for binfmt_misc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html), a binfmt_misc rule can be based on the file contents - for example, looking for a magic number - rather than on the file extension.  The example rule they give for Wine is

```
:DOSWin:M::MZ::/usr/local/bin/wine:
```

As you don't have Wine installed, removing the rule entirely is the right fix.  If you ever install Wine and *do* want to be able to run Windows binaries in the same way that Linux binaries can be run, you should use a rule like the example rule, rather than a rule telling the kernel to assume anything ending with .exe is a Windows executable.

Comment: to be honest I don't remember if I configured the binfmt_misc rule in the past myself or if it came with some package or something, anyway thanks for adding useful info to the answer